# Ubuntu 22 is talking after waking up from suspend

Tags: 22.04

I went into settings because it sounds like assistance for visually impaired people but I can't find the switch.

How do I turn it off?

Comment: Ubuntu 22 is Ubuntu Core is that what you are using or is the tag correct it is Ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 22.04 you will find the setting in `Settings > Accessibility`

The first switch is to `Always Show Accessibility Menu` which by default is usually set to off.

Turn this setting to on and you will see a person icon appear on the System Tray.

Click on that and from the drop down menu uncheck the slider for *Screen Reader*

If you no longer require the Accessibility icon on the System Tray, simply turn off the `Always Show Accessibility Menu` switch.

The Screen Reader switch can also be accessed directly from the `Settings > Accessibility` menu under the `Seeing` section.